# PHP errors when migrating a joomla site to another server

Tags: joomla, php

When I switch my joomla site to another server, it shows this error:

```
Non-static method JApplication::getMenu() should not be called statically, 
assuming$this   from incompatible context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the result of the PHP error reporting.

Joomla contains some coding issues, some more subtle than others and those trigger `Strict` and `Notice` messages.

You can handle this by telling the PHP engine to hide those messages by editing the following directive in your `php.ini` file :

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use Akeeba back to get your joomla site backup. & Using kickstart file set up it where ever you want. Its very easy & simple.